# Handling exceptions from core libs

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

In my current project there is usage of a lot of core Python libraries.
This error comes up: `urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x012D3A60>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it`

The issue lies in the fact that Python throws this exception whenever it encounters it and not its most preferable for the handling of exceptions in the code.
Is there a way to not throw it and keep it throwing it later?
A preferable solution would be to not edit the library it self.

The following code has been tried:

```
from io import StringIO

stdout_buffer = StringIO()
sys.stdout = stdout_buffer
```

but got no results.
A few more random ideas in-between but nothing seemed to work.

Comment: `urllib3` isn't a core library. And exceptions need to be handled. Trying to capture the output of the exception after it reached the top level where it ends the interpreter doesn't help.  And editing the library wouldn't help either because you would need to replace the `raise` of the exception with something sensible. What would that be?

Comment: What would you suggest to try out? I'm out of ideas of ways to approach this without being destructive.

Comment: Handle the exception at the appropriate level with the appropriate code.  You can't ignore it, that's the point of having exceptions in a programming language in the first place, that unlike special error return values, exceptional/error program states have to be dealt with at _some_ level.  Where that is and what should be done at that point depends on the individual use case.

Comment: I never stated that the intention was to ignore it. My question is how to handle this exception myself, I want to format it before throwing it for easier readability.
I've already stated above what I thought and what I tried, if you have any ideas/solutions feel free to help me.

Comment: It wasn't clear to me from the question that you wanted to reformat it. I'm also not convinced that's a good idea because there are no real guarantees the message will always look that way.  For instance the last part isn't even generated by the Python code but is an error message from the operating system.  Where do you see the exception?  Does it bubble up to the interpreter and ends the program? Then you might want to have a look at `sys.excepthook`.

Comment: I'm truly sorry for the delay, I appreciate your answer and sorry for non-clarity on my part.
1. It comes up in remote systems.
2. It clogs up the logging system we have in place since the last part of the exception is dynamic and out systems don't have regex to distinguish that they are the same exception.
3. I know its not a good idea, in general I want to print the original error but then throw a smaller exception so the systems wont clog